# Is there any free good google or bing interactive map?

Tags: google-maps

I already have a list of the all stores with their lad and lon. I am looking to hook this list with map. map will display the store names and other key data. possible?

Answer (score 4):

Both google maps and the bing maps API needs a licence if its on a password protected site. Google maps API is free if its on an internet facing and not password protected site iirc.

Check out [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) if you need a 100% free alternative

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to render Map in List View for [XSLTListViewWebPart (XLV)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff806162%28v=office.14%29.aspx) using [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/).

### Solution description

For storing geographical locations and visualizing it in Map is used **Custom List**. Custom List is based on Generic List with Custom Content Type and with View to render Map.

Map List View is implemented using custom XSLT style sheet and JavaScript rendering control for Map.

For implementation details please see my blog post [Bringing Map functionality into SharePoint 2010: Rendering Map List View](http://vgrem.wordpress.com/2012/12/21/bringing-map-functionality-into-sharepoint-2010-rendering-map-list-view/)

### Usage

After deployment of solution new List Template named GeoMap List will be available.

In order to visualize stores on map, we create list instance of GeoMap List.

After saving information about stores 
[image]

switch to **Map View** to visualize stores on map
[image]